# Ansible with OpenSUSE transactional server

Tags: ansible, linux

When using an OpenSUSE transactional server, transactional-update must be used instead of [`Zypper`](https://en.opensuse.org/images/1/17/Zypper-cheat-sheet-1.pdf). Is there any way of doing this with Ansible?

Comment: You also need to consider, that all changes in `/etc/` must be applied differently, i.e. in `transactional-update run` (or shell) and you don't have access to all locations from there, e.g. `/home`, where ansible usually stores temporary data.

Answer (score 1):

I think currently the only way is to use the command (or shell) module, as there's no native support for transactional-updates in Ansible yet.
However, there's a fresh feature request issue: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/3159

For example:

```
- name: install a package with transactional-update
  ansible.builtin.command:  transactional-update --continue pkg install man
```

Multiple package names can be added.
The parameter `--continue` is important, as otherwise only the last call to `transactional-update` will get effective.

Another downside is, that a reboot is required, which can be triggered from Ansible, but that kills the Ansible run....